# Disabling specific dates for Kendo UI Datepicker in Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to disable specific dates in Kendo UI's Datepicker component? I am aware that the current API does not support it but does anyone know a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI team's response to my question:

**Datepicker**

```
<kendo-datepicker (open)="onOpen()"></kendo-datepicker>
```

**Function**

```
onOpen(e){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      document.querySelector('.k-widget.k-calendar.k-calendar-infinite .k-calendar-view .k-content.k-scrollable').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        this.disableDates()
      })

      this.disableDates()

   })
}

public disableDates(){
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr td')).forEach(td => {
        if(td.getAttribute('title') == 'Wednesday, July 4, 2018'){
          td.classList.add('disabled')
        }
      })
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled{
     pointer-events: none;
     opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**Plunker:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/f32f4pKDf4zwVyshZdfJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to "fake" disabled dates by visualizing and preventing the selection of those dates.

#### Step 1 - visualize disabled dates

Style the disabled dates by utilizing the `kendoCalendarMonthCellTemplate` directive.
e.g. via a `disabled` class

```
<kendo-datepicker>
    <ng-template kendoCalendarMonthCellTemplate let-date>
        <span [class.disabled]="isDateDisabled(date)">
            {{ date.getDate() }}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

#### Step 2 - prevent selection of disabled dates

In the `valueChange` event set the previous selected date if the selected date is disabled.

```
onValueChange(newDate: Date) {
    if (this.isDateDisabled(newDate)) {
        this.date = this.lastDate;
    } else {
        this.date = newDate;
        this.lastDate = newDate;
    }
}
```

I've created an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/iC1EMAT7yJ9lTQOTlN4j?p=preview) showing this approach in action.

In the provided example I've also added a few tweaks.
(e.g.: do not close the calendar if the selected date is disabled)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time answering my question. I recently just received a response from the Kendo UI team answering the same question I had and I will be posting it here as well.